# Tab-triggered snippets in shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, bash-completion, zsh-completion

Is there a way to use tab key in bash or zsh to trigger a snippet, like e.g. Sublime Text does it?

For example, if I have configured that `x` should be expanded to `~/projects/one/two/x/`, so:

```
$ cd x[TAB]
```

would turn into

```
$ cd ~/projects/one/two/x/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite easy in zsh, actually.

First, you need a shell function that does whatever you want if the conditions are met (here, if the zle special variable `$LBUFFER` — that is, what's at the left of the current position in the zle buffer — is `x`) and fallbacks to the regular completion otherwise:

```
expandSnippetOrComplete() {
    [[ $LBUFFER = x ]] && LBUFFER=~/projects/one/two/x/ || zle expand-or-complete
}
```

Second, you have to make this shell function a zle widget, that is, a function that can be called within zle instead of from the command line.

```
zle -N expandSnippetOrComplete
```

Third, you have to bind this widget to the tab key:

```
bindkey "^i" expandSnippetOrComplete
```

That's it!

Now, you might want to do that if the last word before the current position in the zle buffer is `x`, be it at the beginning or not. If so, then this should do the trick:

```
local ALBUFFER
ALBUFFER=($=LBUFFER) # split $LBUFFER on $IFS, put the resulting in $ALBUFFER
[[ $ALBUFFER[-1] = x ]] && LBUFFER[-1]=~/projects/one/two/x/ || zle expand-or-complete
```

Comment: The benefit over using the completion system is that you can actually bind this to whatever key you want, be it the same as for completion or not.